# Trying to create custom textview but showing error

Tags: android, textview

Here is my code for class `test.java`

```
package com.example.testdroid;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class test extends TextView{

    public test(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.setText("Hello World");
        this.setTextSize(20f);
        this.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }   
    protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
     }       
}
```

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

 <com.example.testdroid.test
        android:id="@+id/test1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="68dp"
       />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat :

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testdroid/com.example.testdroid.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class com.example.testdroid.test

Comment: you forgot about other constructors ... infalter expects the one with attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class for textview like as follow:-

```
public class TextViews extends TextView{

    public TextViews (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public TextViews (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public TextViews (Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            this.setText("Hello World");
            this.setTextSize(20f);
            this.setTextColor(Color.RED);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Clairvoyant :) i'm trying to vote up but it show error , 15 reputation required,..